# Getting Failure/error and NoMethod Error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The following is my search method from the controller

```
@accounts = []
    client = GameAccounts::GameAccountsClient.new



    if params[:name]


      # Try and find a game account by id using the given name
      response = client.get_accounts_by_name(params[:name])

      if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
        account = client.parse_json(response)
        unless account.empty?
          session[:account] = account
          redirect_to game_account_path(params[:name])
        end
      end

      json = client.get_json(params[:limit],params[:offset],params[:name])

      @presenter = GameAccountsPresenter.new(json)

    end
  end
```

I am trying to run the following test :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GameAccountsController do
  describe 'GET search' do
    it 'finds a named system account directly' do
     get(:search, name: 'test').to be_redirect_to(game_account_path('test'))
    end
  end
end
```

I keep getting a

```
GameAccountsController GET search finds a named system account directly
     Failure/Error: get(:search, name: 'test').to be_redirect_to(game_account_path('test'))
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007f8b0beb3e10>
     # ./spec/controllers/game_accounts_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

can anyone please let me know what i am doing wrong ?? .. tried doing `.should redirect_to` and i still get the same error but with method 'should'.

Client code

module GameAccounts
  class GameAccountsClient

```
OAUTH_CONFIG=YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config','oauth.yml' ))
def consumer
  @consumer ||= OAuth::Consumer.new(OAUTH_CONFIG['oauth_key'],OAUTH_CONFIG['oauth_secret'],access_token_url: OAUTH_CONFIG['oauth_access_token_url'],signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1')
end

def get_accounts_by_name(name)
   query_account(CGI.escape(name))
end

def get_accounts_by_id(account_id)
  response = query_account(CGI.escape(account_id))
  parse_json(response)
end

def get_json(limit,offset,name)

  limit=set_limit(limit)

  offset = set_offset(offset)

  query = "?name=#{CGI.escape(name)}&limit=#{limit}#{offset}"
  response = query_account(query)
  parse_json(response)
end


def parse_json(response)
   JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rspec's request specs can be tricky. You should call the 'get' method with you params, this will create a response method where your actual response data is being held:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GameAccountsController do
  describe 'GET search' do
    it 'finds a named system account directly' do
      get(:search, name: 'test')
      response.should redirect_to(game_account_path('test'))
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps :)

**Edit:**

Here's a link to [rspec's documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec), version 2.13 supports the `expect` syntax. The above example could also be written as:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GameAccountsController do
  describe 'GET search' do
    it 'finds a named system account directly' do
      get(:search, name: 'test')
      expect(response).to redirect_to(game_account_path('test'))
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit 2:**

Try the following code and test the return values (and classes) of the get_* methods:

```
def search
  @accounts = []

  if params[:name]

    if get_response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
      unless get_account.empty?
        session[:account] = get_account
        redirect_to game_account_path(params[:name])
      end
    end

    json = get_client.get_json(params[:limit],params[:offset],params[:name])
    @presenter = GameAccountsPresenter.new(json)

  end
end

def get_client
  @client ||= GameAccounts::GameAccountsClient.new
end

# Try and find a game account by id using the given name
def get_response
  @response ||= client.get_accounts_by_name(params[:name])
end

def get_account
  @account ||= get_client.parse_json(get_response)
end
```

Comment: Thank you @sergelerator for your reply but Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(system_account_path('test'))
       Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200> is what i am getting now :(

Comment: This time the test is "properly failing", now you have to make it pass. I was wondering why were you doing this: `if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)`

The `response` variable is most likely a collection of accounts, but since you just created the `client` it will be an empty collection. I'll update my answer with a suggestion on how to fix that but I might not fully understand what you're trying to accomplish here, maybe you could share your data models?

Comment: Hey sorry for getting back until now. You're getting a 200 (an OK) response. That means the redirect was not performed, try to break your method a little more by moving `response = client.get_accounts_by_name(params[:name])` to a separate method, and test it's return value. I have a feeling it's not a `Net::HTTPSuccess`. Once you figure that one out, move `account = client.parse_json(response)` to a `get_account` method and test if it's empty (it should not). Once you make that pass, you 'll get to `redirect_to game_account_path(params[:name])` and your test should be green :)